# XML Extraction issue with xmlns

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml

I have some standard XML code that I am trying to extract, I have read up on a variety of different questions regarding xmlns and have my code up to this point, but what I can't seem to do is extract the text inside the " " for CustomerID -

```
DECLARE @docHandle INT 
DECLARE @XmlDocument NVARCHAR(1000) 
DECLARE @rootxmlns VARCHAR(1000) 

SET @XmlDocument ='  
<Root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">   
 <Customers>     
  <Customer CustomerID="GREAL">       
   <CompanyName>Great Lakes Food Market</CompanyName>       
   <ContactName>Howard Snyder</ContactName>       
   <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>
   <Phone>(503) 555-7555</Phone>       
  </Customer>     
 </Customers>  
</Root>  ' 
SET @rootxmlns = '<Root xmlns:hm="http://www.adventure-works.com"/>' 

-- Create an internal representation of the XML document.   
EXEC Sp_xml_preparedocument 
@docHandle output, 
@XmlDocument, 
@rootxmlns 

-- Execute a SELECT statement using OPENXML rowset provider.   
SELECT * 
FROM   OPENXML (@docHandle, '/hm:Root/hm:Customers', 3) 
      WITH ([CustomerID]           CHAR(10) './hm:CustomerID'
           ,[Customer.CompanyName] VARCHAR(100)'hm:Customer/hm:CompanyName' 
           ,[Customer.ContactName] VARCHAR(100) 
   'hm:Customer/hm:ContactName' ) 

EXEC Sp_xml_removedocument 
@docHandle
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with `FROM OPENXML` together with the stored procedures to create and to remove a XML document is outdated and should not be used any more. Much better, faster and easier to read are [the native XML methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017) (some of them supported since v2005).

I place your XML within a natively declared variable. But you can *inline* this approach into any query against table data, which allows for XML usage in VIEWs and iTVFs.

```
DECLARE @XmlDocument XML;

SET @XmlDocument ='  
<Root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">   
 <Customers>     
  <Customer CustomerID="GREAL">       
   <CompanyName>Great Lakes Food Market</CompanyName>       
   <ContactName>Howard Snyder</ContactName>       
   <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>
   <Phone>(503) 555-7555</Phone>       
  </Customer>     
 </Customers>  
</Root>';
```

--First of all we declare the default namespace (`xmlns="Some URI"`)

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.adventure-works.com') 
SELECT c.value('(Customer/@CustomerID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CustomerID
      ,c.value('(Customer/CompanyName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CompanyName
      ,c.value('(Customer/ContactName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ContactName
      ,c.value('(Customer/ContactTitle/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ContactTitle
      ,c.value('(Customer/Phone/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Phone
FROM @XmlDocument.nodes('/Root/Customers') A(c)
```

From the plural of `<Customers>` I assume, that there might be multiple customers within one XML. That's why I use `.nodes()` in order to get a derived table with all customers (will be returned as *row-wise* per customer).

The `.value()`-method will read the specific value typed as provided in the second argument.

Comment: Thanks Shnugo for your response, can you please advice me as to what the [1] means in the middle of c.value('(Customer/CompanyName/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CompanyName

Comment: @S.Ryan, `. value() ` needs a *singleton*. This will return the **first** value found for the given XPath.

Comment: very quick with the response again, so thankyou. Last question that I have, does the '@' next to c.value('(Customer/@CustomerID)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS CustomerID indicate that it is going to extract text within " "?

Comment: @S.Ryan Within an XML there are *elements* and *attributes*. In an `XPath/XQuery`-expression the attributes are marked with the `@`. The above is reading the *attribute `@CustomerID`* within the *element `<Customer>`*.